# What are the options for network programming in Go?

Tags: sockets, go

I am looking to write a simple client/server utilizing TCP sockets. Any ideas how to do network programming in Go?

Comment: Check out the [net](http://golang.org/pkg/net/) package.

Answer (score 5):

Go has fine support for networking.

For a server, the easiest thing to do is have your `main()` start a tcp accept loop and spawn a goroutine to handle each request.

The first go software I wrote was a memcached server.  You may want to [check out gomemcached](http://github.com/dustin/gomemcached) for an idea of how to get started on servers.

Clients shouldn't be particularly harder.  In many cases, it may make the most sense to have a shared client with goroutines for inbound communication much like I use in gomemcached for communicating with the actual storage layer.

Of course, this isn't the only way.  Perhaps you'll find something better as you experiment.